# PHP Wordpress: Handling user submitted data?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Okay, so I have a form for user submitted data and I'd like some feedback on security (using PHP on wordpress):

What I want from my form:

1. Text data (paragraph long). No need for anything but alphanumeric and some English punctuation, but also want to be able to handle other languages at a basic level.
2. Image data (multiple images).

I start with a form that takes in the data. I have a function that strips most stuff, but I want to keep ' (single quote) and ! (exclamation mark). I am also curious about what basic step I can take to protect my MySQL database before the data gets added?

I found this function for stripping, but still takes away (single quote and exclamation mark):

```
function strip_punctuation( $content ) 
{

$urlbrackets    = '\[\]\(\)';
$urlspacebefore = ':;\'_\*%@&?!' . $urlbrackets;
$urlspaceafter  = '\.,:;\'\-_\*@&\/\\\\\?!#' . $urlbrackets;
$urlall         = '\.,:;\'\-_\*%@&\/\\\\\?!#' . $urlbrackets;

$specialquotes  = '\'"\*<>';

$fullstop       = '\x{002E}\x{FE52}\x{FF0E}';
$comma          = '\x{002C}\x{FE50}\x{FF0C}';
$arabsep        = '\x{066B}\x{066C}';
$numseparators  = $fullstop . $comma . $arabsep;

$numbersign     = '\x{0023}\x{FE5F}\x{FF03}';
$percent        = '\x{066A}\x{0025}\x{066A}\x{FE6A}\x{FF05}\x{2030}\x{2031}';
$prime          = '\x{2032}\x{2033}\x{2034}\x{2057}';
$nummodifiers   = $numbersign . $percent . $prime;

return preg_replace(
    array(
    // Remove separator, control, formatting, surrogate,
    // open/close quotes.
        '/[\p{Z}\p{Cc}\p{Cf}\p{Cs}\p{Pi}\p{Pf}]/u',
    // Remove other punctuation except special cases
        '/\p{Po}(?<![' . $specialquotes .
            $numseparators . $urlall . $nummodifiers . '])/u',
    // Remove non-URL open/close brackets, except URL brackets.
        '/[\p{Ps}\p{Pe}](?<![' . $urlbrackets . '])/u',
    // Remove special quotes, dashes, connectors, number
    // separators, and URL characters followed by a space
        '/[' . $specialquotes . $numseparators . $urlspaceafter .
            '\p{Pd}\p{Pc}]+((?= )|$)/u',
    // Remove special quotes, connectors, and URL characters
    // preceded by a space
        '/((?<= )|^)[' . $specialquotes . $urlspacebefore . '\p{Pc}]+/u',
    // Remove dashes preceded by a space, but not followed by a number
        '/((?<= )|^)\p{Pd}+(?![\p{N}\p{Sc}])/u',
    // Remove consecutive spaces
        '/ +/',
    ),
    ' ',
    $content );
}
```

Any ideas how to get ' (single quote) and ! (exclamation point) back as allowed? Also, what is the easiest way to protect the MySQL database before entry?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to protect input by removing elements like punctuation/weird characters, just encode your input or output (Not both) with `htmlspecialchars()`. As far as mysql security, just make sure to sanitize your variables. See `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, or even better, binding variables to your query.

Comment: FrankerZ is a bit out of touch. Prepared and bound statements (preferably using pdo) are the correct way to provide security

Comment: As for allowing ! and ' - come on, you can figure that bit out